# Rails, Cucumber and localized messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, localization, cucumber

I'm writing an application and I'm using localization everywhere I can. The problem is that I would like to test it using cucumber. I don't
want to update the tests everytime the translation is changed. Is it possible to make cucumber understand something like that:

```
When I am logged in
Then I should see t(:login_ok)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not tested, but I believe something like this should work:

```
Then /I should see t\(:?([^\)]*)\)/ do |text|
  Then "I should see #{I18n.translate(text)}"
end
```

This should be in `features/step_definitions/???_steps.rb`

Comment: Thanks, this more or less worked - just corrected it to look like:Then /^I press t"([^"]*)"$/ do |text|
  click_button(I18n.translate(text))
end

Then /^I should see t"([^"]*)"/ do |text|
  page.should have_content(I18n.translate(text)) 
end

Comment: This is cool because you get to test your translation keys as well.